# I'm experience FileNotFoundError in my code

Tags: python, graphviz

when i tried using Graphviz package after it has been install successfully in visual environment
i still get the follow error.

```
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute WindowsPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz 
executables are on your systems' PATH
\<graphviz.sources.Source at 0x1fdbb44bf40\>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the graphviz package in your system. On Ubuntu try:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing graphviz package in your system.
for windows use this: https://graphviz.org/download/#windows

then after that use graphviz in your code like this:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for assisting me I used the code, and it works and i didnt have that previous error again, but it develops another error... the error is showing now is as follows; CalledProcessError: Command '[WindowsPath('dot'), '-Kdot', '-Tsvg']' returned non-zero exit status 3221225595. [stderr: '']
<graphviz.sources.Source at 0x22a3fbff3a0>